# How do i introduce 3 functions at once?

Tags: c++

My problem is that i have three functions and they are calling each other. Then i get an error that function was not declared in scope.

```
int X {
  y = Y();
  return y+10;
}

int Y {
  z = Z();
  return z+15;
}

int Z {
 x = X();
 y = Y();
 return x+y;
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Try to make brackets after X() and write in the top of the file int X(); int Y(); int Z(); This will act as placeholder, until the function gets declared

Comment: this is suggesting a (possibly) infinite indirect recursion

Comment: Thank you for giving me right answer, and @Harald was right. I should write int Y(); int X(); int Z(); at top!